# html/CSS text-align not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to center some text in a modal window, but i cannot get the text centered.

my html code is:

```
<div ng-init="modalCompassDir()">
    <div class="myModal">
        <img class='floorImage' src={{items}}/>
        <div class="stickFigureDiv">
            <img class="stickFigure" style="height:30px; width:30px;" src="NavAppPics/stick_figure.gif"/>
            <img class="directionArrow" degrees='angle' rotate src='NavAppPics/transparentArrow.png' style="height:28px; width:25px;"  />
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="address">{{address}}</a>

</div>
```

my CSS code is:

```
.myModal{
    position:relative;
    display: block;
/*    height:300px;*/
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.address{
    font-size:1.5em;
    text-align: center;
/*    margin-left:10%;*/

}
```

i cannot figure out why the text-align in my CSS is not working, as i have ben following this example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

edit: i changed one of the text-align to center,  i was testing a few things and copied the code before i changed it back

Comment: why would the address align center, when you have `text-align: right`?

Comment: i just added an edit,  i was testing to see if any text align would work and i forgot to change it back before posting.  sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display: block` to your `a` element. By default `a` elements are `inline` and `inline` elements have width which depends on the content where `text-align` won't have effect unless you set it inside their container.

```
.address{
    font-size:1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/um7rrjoj/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-init="modalCompassDir()">
    <div class="myModal">
        <img class='floorImage' src={{items}}/>
        <div class="stickFigureDiv">
            <img class="stickFigure" style="height:30px; width:30px;" src="NavAppPics/stick_figure.gif"/>
            <img class="directionArrow" degrees='angle' rotate src='NavAppPics/transparentArrow.png' style="height:28px; width:25px;"  />
        </div>
        <a class="address">{{address}}</a>
    </div>
```

put .address inside .myModal

Answer (score 0):

Put your .address link inside .myModal or add a class to the parent div and use text align center on this class like this:

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-init="modalCompassDir()" class='custom_class'>
    <div class="myModal">
        <img class='floorImage' src={{items}}/>
        <div class="stickFigureDiv">
            <img class="stickFigure" style="height:30px; width:30px;" src="NavAppPics/stick_figure.gif"/>
            <img class="directionArrow" degrees='angle' rotate src='NavAppPics/transparentArrow.png' style="height:28px; width:25px;"  />
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="address">{{address}}</a>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.myModal{
    position:relative;
    display: block;
/*    height:300px;*/
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.address{
    font-size:1.5em;
    text-align: right;
/*    margin-left:10%;*/
}
.custom_class{
  text-align:center;
}
```